# JavaME/LWUIT/Blackberry - how to get lcdui's Display in RIMlet?

Tags: blackberry, java-me, lwuit

I have a LWUIT-application which I also want to run on Blackberry phones. For this I use the approach from the LWUIT Demo App - common implementation is placed in a separate project (the base), there is 1 more separate project for MIDP which depends on the base, 1 other for RIM which also deps on the base. The project for RIM produces a native RIM application. In RIM's world it's called CLDC app or RIMlet. So, my application is not derived from MIDlet, but from UiApplication. See below.

```
import net.rim.device.api.ui.UiApplication;

public class MyRimlet extends UiApplication implements Runnable {
```

Now the problem...
I use some library. The class from that library needs lcdui's Display for its initialization (ref2 javax.microedition.lcdui.Display). I can get a ref2 Display if I have MIDlet. For this I can use Display.getDisplay(MIDlet m) method. But I don't have MIDlet since my app is derived from UiApplication.
So, what should I do to initialize the class from external lib?

Please help me regarding this.

Comment: Check `net.rim.device.api.system.Display`, http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.3.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/Display.html

Comment: That interface is different and it doesn't provide lcdui's Display interface.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you cannot mix LWUIT components with J2ME components, as far as I know. My knowledge could be dated though.
But I have used the approach provided [here](http://www.lwuit.com/2009/11/building-project-on-blackberry.html) successfully earlier.

However, I must mention that it is possible to develop UI components that can work on both J2ME as well as Blackberry by making use of [BlackberryCanvas](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.7.0api/net/rim/device/api/lcdui/BlackBerryCanvas.html). I am almost sure LWUIT is doing something similar.

Using the Widgets apart, the way you start the application would be different. You will have to create a CLDC application on Blackberry; you cannot use MIDlet.